# using a function on textbox focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, focus

I want to add a autocomplete function to a site and found this guide which uses some js code which works really nice for one textbox: http://www.sks.com.np/article/9/ajax-autocomplete-using-php-mysql.html

However when trying to add multiple autocompletes only the last tetbox will work since it is the last one set.

Here is the function that sets the variables for the js script

```
function setAutoComplete(field_id, results_id, get_url)
{

// initialize vars
acSearchId  = "#" + field_id;
acResultsId = "#" + results_id;
acURL       = get_url;

// create the results div
$("#auto").append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');

// register mostly used vars
acSearchField   = $(acSearchId);
acResultsDiv    = $(acResultsId);

// reposition div
repositionResultsDiv();

// on blur listener
acSearchField.blur(function(){ setTimeout("clearAutoComplete()", 200) });

// on key up listener
acSearchField.keyup(function (e) {

    // get keyCode (window.event is for IE)
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || window.event.keyCode;
    var lastVal = acSearchField.val();

    // check an treat up and down arrows
    if(updownArrow(keyCode)){
        return;
    }

    // check for an ENTER or ESC
    if(keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 27){
        clearAutoComplete();
        return;
    }

    // if is text, call with delay
    setTimeout(function () {autoComplete(lastVal)}, acDelay);
});
}
```

For one textbox I can call the function like this

```
$(function(){      
setAutoComplete("field", "fieldSuggest", "/functions/autocomplete.php?part=");
});
```

However when using multiple textboxes I am unsure how I should go about doing this, here is something I did try but it did not work

```
$('#f1').focus(function (e) {   
    setAutoComplete("f1", "fSuggest1", "/functions/autocomplete.php?q1=");
}
$('#f2').focus(function (e) {   
    setAutoComplete("f2", "fSuggest2", "/functions/autocomplete.php?q2=");
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you add listener each time the element get the focus? You should initilize each element with your function

Comment: What does clearAutoComplete do?  Does it clear out the divs appended to the #auto? Multiple fields with the same id could cause problems, but you should firstly change it Bouillou's suggestion, secondly what do you mean by it's not working. Are there any errors on the JS console? If there are duplicated elements with the same id, and you inspect the elements, do you see results going into one, but trying to display another. e.g. <div style="display: none;" id="f1"><ul><li>res1</li></ul></div> <!-- results there --> <div id="f1"></div> <!-- visible div -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using classes to make your function work in more than one element on the same page. Just drop the fixed ID's and do a forEach to target every single element with that class.